# deep learning with kfold cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, training-data

I am new into neural networks, I want to use K-fold cross-validation to train my neural network.
I want to use 5 folds
50 epochs 
and a batch size of 64
I found a function in scikit for k-fold cross validation

```
model_selection.cross_val_score(model_kfold, x_train, y_train, cv=5)
```

and my code without cross validation is

```
history = alexNet_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1,validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
```

I don't know how to implement this with batch size and epochs in python using keras and scikit.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use test data when validating your model, not the same training data.  Using training data to validate will bias your results.

In your example, I would use the KerasClassifier module instead of the numpy KFolds module.

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
```

After you've imported the module, your code would be (with results output:

```
evaluator=KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=50, batch_size=64)
kfold=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)

results=cross_val_score(evaluator, x_test, onehot_y_test, cv=kfold)
print("Model: %.2f%% (%.2F%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```